# Add specialisation to single-header "library"

Tags: c++, templates, lazy-evaluation

Currently working on a single-header "library" involving some light TMP, which allows users to add customisations/specialisations for their types (as a self-teaching project with actual use case).

I am having problems with the customisation bit.

### Example

```
// foo_library.h
void foo(int i) {}
void foo(bool b) {}

template<typename T>
void do_something(T t)
{
    foo(t);
}

// user_code.cpp: user adds specialisation for double
void foo(double d) {}

do_something(42);    // ok
do_something(false); // ok
do_something(3.14);  // error: do_something has not seen double overload
```

**Note:** this is about the template instantiation - I know full well that order ("having seen something") matters in the C family.

Knowing that template instantiation is lazy, I assumed the template is instantiated in-place, i.e. having seen the double specialisation. Clearly that is not the case :(

It seems I am missing some fundamental technique or concept, because there *is* code out there that allows users to "inject" their customisations into template-heavy header-only libraries (`std::swap` or nlohmann::json come to mind)

**Question:** What technique do I need to enable this customisation-injection functionality by simply having the user define an appropriate function in some library namespace?

Things I thought of:

- spread implementation over multiple headers and have users include the last one *after* all customizations: Error-prone and probably will not scale to anything but toy projects
- section the header into parts using section-include-guards ([Symbolic C++](http://issc.uj.ac.za/symbolic/symbolic.html) does that, though not for customisation): Would require user opt-in through `EVERY_CUSTOMIZATION_DEFINED_HERE` macro or some such, don't want that.
- wrap things into a class template, hoping instantiation behaves differently. Nope.

Comment: You are missing a concept called two-phase instantiation. Google that, and the notion of dependent names.

Comment: You may want to try defining `foo` as a template, and let the user specialise, rather than overload, it.

Comment: See https://ideone.com/IAebRy BTW the correct term to google is "two phase name lookup", sorry about the confusion.

Comment: @n.m. so the fundamental idea is to replace ADL-driven overloading by template lookup, because that happens later?

Comment: There's no ADL in your code, as fundamental types don't belong to a namespace. For user-defined types ADL would work.

Comment: @n.m. alright, need to catch up on C++'s type system theory, not just skim it :-) One problem with the template approach is that it delays type checking until link time, so if none of the specialisations match, the compiler picks the generic declaration, and the linker will complain with hard-to-read error messages. I guess I could add a body with `static_assert(false, "you cannot call me!")`, but I feel there must be a nicer solution

Comment: You can use `=delete` syntax instead, it's designed exactly for this "you cannot call me" scenario.

Comment: @n.m so, why in your ideone do you believe the call to do_something(3.14) will fail to compile?

Comment: @johnathan It will not fail to compile, I just forgot to change OP's comment.

Comment: A little nitpick: `void foo(double d)` is not a specialization, it's an overload.

Answer (score 0):

As state in comment, there are no ADL for fundamental types, so you can just add dummy parameter (with dependant name):

```
template<typename> struct Tag{};

void foo(int i, Tag<int>) { std::cout << "int:" << i << std::endl;}
void foo(bool b, Tag<bool>) {std::cout << "bool:" << b << std::endl;}

template<typename T>
void do_something(T t)
{
    foo(t, Tag<T>{});
}
```

// user_code.cpp: user adds specialisation for double

```
void foo(double d, Tag<double>) {std::cout << "double:" << d << std::endl;}
int main() {
    do_something(42);    // ok
    do_something(false); // ok
    do_something(3.14);  // use double overload :)
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/eb7c6a10806bd3c3)

Comment: To understand: It seems to me the advantage is that I do not need a `template <typename T> void foo<T>(T t)`, and by injecting the templated type I get 2-phase lookup (i.e. at a later time than overload resolution, which is the thing I need to get this working) - right?